# Access Yahoo weather using Oauth

Tags: python, oauth

Totally lost here. I have a weather station that I developed on Python for a Raspberry PI. Very nice and useful (I am a biker). But it recently stopped working!

I was using weather.com and Yahoo APIs. weather.com is not free since 01/15/2020, and Yahoo now requests an Oauth access that I don't have. I have signed up and I have my AppID, ClientID and SecretCode... But I don't have a clue about what to do with it. After reading a lot, I think that I have to get a Token, but I don't know how to get it and what to do with it (store it on disk???). In addition to that, it seems that it needs to be refreshed from time to time.

Everything I found is on C++, java or php (that I don't understand); and it is very distinct from one source to another, so I am not sure which one to use.

If someone could help me to understand what to do, where to look or an example, I would really appreciate that.

To the moment, I tried this which "promisses" to manage oauth connections, with no success:

```
from yahoo_oauth import OAuth1
oauth = OAuth1(None, None, from_file='oauth1.json')

if not oauth.token_is_valid():
    oauth.refresh_access_token()

# Example
response = oauth.session.post(url, data=body)
```

Nevertheless, I think that this is just to refresh the token, but as I said before, I don't know how to get it and what to do whit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you actually need is here, with python example :)
[Documentation yahoo](https://developer.yahoo.com/weather/documentation.html#oauth-python).

Here are the stepss for setup: [Setup steps](https://developer.yahoo.com/weather/)

What is going on with the token? Yahoo needs some verification that it is you who make request - so you need to add the Authorization token to you request. That's all :)
Ask here, if you had more questions :)

Comment: hahahaha! Can you believe I didn't see the tabs with all languages before? (feeling totally nerd) Thanx, mate! Just one more question... do I have to do that all every time I query the API, or just the first time, or every time the token is expired,.. ?

Comment: Yea sometimes that happends when you're overworked, so take a break man :D the header with Authorization needs to be passed everytime for sure - for the others i don't know unfortunately, but i'd said every time also :) Ofc you get your auth creds only only once

Comment: Thanks again! Now it fails. I guess it is still pending of whitelisting... anyway, I have something to start with. Keep pushing!

Comment: @"Dawid Gace". Working! I had to make some little adjustments since it is based on Python2 and I am working on Python3. In addition to that, the API still has no rain chance data, but I could get it somewhere else. Thanx, mate!

Comment: Great :) I you could try openweathermap.org -  i was using it some time ago, there are some limitations for free users, but for home use what they offer is more than needed!

Comment: I already tried! But not exactly what I needed. First: it is a 3hours forecasts, so it's harder to manage, but "doable". Second: There is no rain chance data which is something that I really appreciate to have (only precipitation volume... which is not easy to convert to rain proabiblity). Then, I am using a mix of Yahoo and Weatherbit. If you need some advice on that, I'll be very keen to explain!